# How to cut door hole in solid wall?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I want to cut doors holes in walls.

What is method to do it?

I prefer to just cut hole and join vertexes to keep shape simple. Consider that wall has some width and is asymmetric on both sides.

Should I extrude edge loop and do some cut or is there other simpler method?

[image: Screenshot of wall]

How can I create edges and vertices on faces intersection?
[image: Screenshot of extruded faces]

Comment: You got a close vote for this question, because you asked for the 'best' method. The best things are usually opinion based which leads to discussions and doesn't fit the Q&A format here. Therefore I changed your title (slightly).

Answer (score 8):

You can use the *[Boolean modifier.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html#boolean-modifier)*
First create a cube, then scale it so that it intersects with where you want the door to be.

[image: The door will be cut where the red line is.]

The hole will be cut where the red line is. Next, click your building and add a boolean modifier. Set it to difference instead of intersect, then set the object to the cube you just created.

[image: Adding a boolean modifier]

Now click apply, and delete the cube used to cut the door. You should end up with something like this:

[image: There's a hole in my house!]

If you enter into edit mode, the extra faces created should automatically be selected. If you want, you can delete the extra faces and get something like this:

[image: Delete extra faces]

To do what you would want, you could select the vertices around the first doorway, press <kbd>F</kbd> to make it a face, then press <kbd>P</kbd> and select *by selection*.

[image: Separate the door from the rest of the mesh.]

This has created a plane that has the exact dimensions of your door. It is a separate object. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go into object mode, click the door plane, and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again, to enter edit mode. Then select everything if it is not already selected, then press <kbd>E</kbd> for extrude.

[image: Extruding the door]

You can then click once it is thick enough, then go back to Object Mode. Move the cube so that it is intersecting with where the door should be projected onto. Then do the same thing I mentioned above with Boolean, only use the cube you created with the door instead of a new cube.

[image: Boolean with cube created from door]
[image: Two identical doors]

Tada, two identical doorways!

Answer (score 4):

You could select the faces you want to use for the door. And use inset <kbd>I</kbd> to create the geometry. You can optionally extrude the door frame, and lower the door sill.

[image]

Comment: Please not change question before you will answer :) I cut door in wall not extrude door :)

Comment: @Chameleon feel free to rollback the edits. I hoped for a few more answers. You can also use the Knife Tool 'K' to cut a door or windows where ever you like.

Comment: Not sure if knife tools will work with it since can damage other faces and it is not to complex for such simple task.

Comment: I guess we can then delete the face in it to cut the door?

Comment: this is an easier way and a blender way to cut a door. :-)

Answer (score 0):

With the [*Knife Tool*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/knife.html?#knife) doors and windows can easily be cut into an existing mesh.
After pressing <kbd>K</kbd> select where to cut when finished press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You can constrain the angle axis <kbd>C</kbd> also make sure that cut through is switched off (<kbd>Z</kbd>).

[image]

[image]

Comment: See images from question. I do not want cut door hole in cube or in plane since it is ready - I need to project this hole do asymmetric wall behind. This answer miss question.

Comment: @Chameleon then might want to try the cut through option. sorry if I missed the point. Perhaps someone else has more luck with this ;-)

Comment: Cut through is not good I think since you can cut though the next wall too.

Comment: You can select and hide 'H' geometry that you don't want to cut before using the knife tool.

Comment: then you could just use shift + k to cut through the whole model and edit the second door then?

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems I have found with a boolean modifier is it makes an absolute hash of the mesh. Using this method means sorting out any stray verts that get created by the cut which create N-gons which in turn makes it very difficult to add loop cuts for any more detailed modelling later down the line (stuff like outer pillars of the house, adding in support beams etc.)

If I'm not mistaken, I'd say that the doors will be the very last thing to cut out after anything else in the design has been finalised to make workflow go a bit smoother.